# What is the difference between Abstract and Author Summary?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals

What is the difference between "Abstract" and "Author Summary"?

**Example:** [OpenAWSEM with Open3SPN2: A fast, flexible, and accessible framework for large-scale coarse-grained biomolecular simulations](https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1008308)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For journals that have both, the abstract is typically intended to be a technical summary of the article for the core audience, while the author summary or popular summary is written in a less technical style and for a broader audience.

For the linked example, this is laid out in the journal's [Submission guidelines](https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/s/submission-guidelines#loc-abstract):

> **Author Summary**
>
> We ask that all authors of research articles include a 150-200 word non-technical summary of the work as part of the manuscript to immediately follow the abstract. This text is subject to editorial change, should be written in the first-person voice, and should be distinct from the scientific abstract.